# Bash: `test` finds file but `source` wont

Tags: bash, test, virtualenv

I use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/) to manage my Python environments. My global `postactivate` file — a Bash script that gets sourced, after a virtual environment is activated — contains the following:

```
if [ -f 'activate.sh' ]; then
  echo 'activate virtualenv settings'
  source 'activate.sh'
fi
```

This should source the `activate.sh` file only if the project that is connected to the virtual environment contains such a file. But if I use the `workon` command on a project that contains such a file, I get the following output and error:

```
activate virtualenv settings
/home/…/.virtualenvs/postactivate: Zeile 15: source: activate.sh: Datei nicht gefunden.
```

So, the test seems to find the `activate.sh` file but line 15 throws an error (that's the line with `source activate.sh` and the error translates to *file not found*). Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in POSIX conformance mode (like when called as `sh` or when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment), when the argument to `source` doesn't contain any slash character, `bash` looks for it in `$PATH` like POSIX requires for the `.` utility (the standard equivalent of `bash`'s `source`) not the current directory.

If it's a `sh` script you should:

1. Use `.`, not <strike>`source`</strike> which is not `sh`/standard.
2. Use `. ./file`, if you mean to source the `file` in the current directory, not <strike>`. file`</strike> which would source the first `file` found in a `$PATH` lookup.